# how to calculate over dispersion in a non poisson lmer model

Tags: r, lme4

**Hello everyone**, I'm looking to calculate the over dispersion in the following model :

```
lmer(R_ger_b~espece*traitement+(1|pop), data=d)
```

Here "espece" means species, "traitement" means treatment and "pop" means population. My variable called R_ger_b come from a binary variable on which I took the residu out (R_ger_b) to correct this variable from an other one (that was a 0 (non sprouted), 1 (sprouted) variable).

By doing the summary of this model I have this output :

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: R_ger_b ~ espece * traitement + (1 | pop)
   Data: d

REML criterion at convergence: 2381.2

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0555 -0.8182  0.2951  0.6854  1.6788 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 pop      (Intercept) 0.05762  0.24    
 Residual             1.12301  1.06    
Number of obs: 800, groups:  pop, 4

Fixed effects:
                            Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                  0.40383    0.20010   3.20699   2.018  0.13097    
especemac                   -0.88576    0.28298   3.20699  -3.130  0.04756 *  
traitementmi                 0.16897    0.14987 790.00000   1.127  0.25989    
traitementpeu               -0.06180    0.14987 790.00000  -0.412  0.68018    
traitementtemoin            -0.06635    0.14987 790.00000  -0.443  0.65811    
especemac:traitementmi      -0.13861    0.21194 790.00000  -0.654  0.51330    
especemac:traitementpeu      0.18556    0.21194 790.00000   0.876  0.38155    
especemac:traitementtemoin   0.74192    0.21194 790.00000   3.501  0.00049 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
               (Intr) espcmc trtmntm trtmntp trtmntt espcmc:trtmntm espcmc:trtmntp
especemac      -0.707                                                             
traitementm    -0.374  0.265                                                      
traitementp    -0.374  0.265  0.500                                               
traitmnttmn    -0.374  0.265  0.500   0.500                                       
espcmc:trtmntm  0.265 -0.374 -0.707  -0.354  -0.354                               
espcmc:trtmntp  0.265 -0.374 -0.354  -0.707  -0.354   0.500                       
espcmc:trtmntt  0.265 -0.374 -0.354  -0.354  -0.707   0.500          0.500
```

But I don't really know how to calculate over dispersion there, I saw a solution about this problem on a poisson lmer but not in the case I'm working on.

Thank you for your help, I hope I asked my question well

Germain VITAL

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Overdispersion is not a thing that makes sense for a gaussian model like that.

Comment: Even if my response variable is coming from a binary variable ? Thank you for your answer

Comment: You didn't do anything to model that in your code as far as I can tell.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really get what you are saying. Is over dispersion calculation wrong even if my data come from a binary variable ? I have to admit that the fact I took the residues of a binary variable from a glm as new response variable disturbs me.

Comment: What I am saying is that you got a model that assumes a gaussian response. You haven't modeled the binary nature of your data at all anointing to what you've provided. And for a gaussian model overdispersion is not something that makes sense.

Comment: Let's take a step back. You've apparently read that overdispersion is something that can occur with Poisson regression. Why are you so interested in it for your case? What is the reason you need is so badly and what do you plan on doing with the estimate once you have it?

Comment: Does it make sense for you to put a binomial link in a Generalized Linear Mixed Models even if my values are residues ? We calculated over dispersion in one of my class and I thought it was a good thing to test the signification of your model instead of the usual conditions of application. Thank you for your help

Comment: Honestly I don't think you have a programming issue as much as you need some help understanding your model/data. It's not completely clear to me what you mean by residue. Are you saying your response in this model is the residual from a previous model? If so I'm not sure why you would do that. But once again... That's not necessarily a programming issue.

Comment: Yes I took the residuals from a previous model because I wanted to standardized the effect of light variable (that had a large variation inside the same treatment ) on my germination variable. My programming question will be : is it possible to make a binomial glmm with those kind of residus or is it insane ? Sorry if my question isn't appropriate!

Comment: That's not really a programming question though. And it really isn't what you asked in your question. I'd suggest refining your question to make it more clear and easily digestible and posting the refined version to the stats stackexchange site.

Comment: I will do that, thank you again